# Slight Confusion in proof of this theorem

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

I asked for the backwards direction on this proof before. I am concerned if I am able to use this theorem in the proof, even though this is a theorem that a collection is a basis for a known topology:

Theorem:

Let $(X,\tau)$ be a topological space, and let $\mathcal{B}$ be a collection of subsets of $X$. Then $\mathcal{B}$ is a basis for $\tau$ if and only if

$(1) \mathcal{B} \subset \tau$ and

$(2)$ for each set $U$ in $\tau$ and point $p$ in $U$ there is a set $V$ in $\mathcal{B}$ such that $p \in V \subset U$.

Theorem(trying to prove):Suppose $X$ is a set and $\mathcal{B}$ is a collection of subsets of $X$. Then $\mathcal{B}$ is a basis for some topology if and only if

$(1)$ each point of $X$ is in some element of $\mathcal{B}$ and

$(2)$ if $U$ and $V$ are sets in $\mathcal{B}$ and $p$ is a point in $U \cap V$, there is a set $W$ in $\mathcal{B}$ such that $p \in W \subset (U \cap V)$.

($\Rightarrow$)

Since $\mathcal{B}$ is a basis, $X$ can be expressed as the union of elements of $\mathcal{B}$, so each point in $X$ is in some basis element. If $U,V \in\mathcal{B}$ since $U,V$ are open, $U \cap V$ is also open.Let $x \in U \cap V$. Since $U \cap V$ is open there exists a basis element $W$ such that $x \in W \subset U \cap V$.

Clearly I used the first theorem given in this proof. My question is, is it justified to use this result? Thanks

Comment: Sure, as long as you’ve already proved that result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Actually what you refer as the first theorem is the definition of a topological basis. So it is okay to use it in the proof of that theorem.